# Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd) with JSPs

Tags: java, jsp, runtime.exec

I have a class with a method that works just find when I run it from the command line. Nothing seems to happen when I call it in a JSP file though. Could I be missing something here? Are there some configuration changes I need to make to have this code working.

```
public static void toText(String pdfFile, String textFile) {
    try {
        String[] cmd = {"pdftotext", pdfFile, "/tmp/text1984.txt"};
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
        p.waitFor();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.print(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Regards,
Phiri

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can have 2 causes:

1. Your webbrowser doesn't run at the same machine as webserver while you're expecting that Java from webserver also runs in webbrowser (which is ultimately untrue).
2. The servletcontainer where the JSP runs simply failed to execute the command, which can have a lot of causes, such as insufficient permissions or the command just error'ed.

Cause #1 is to be solved by running the Java code in webbrowser instead. This can be done with help of a signed(!) applet. As to cause #2, to nail down its root cause, read [this article](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html) to learn how to understand and debug "Runtime.exec() does nothing" problems. Read all the 4 pages.

Comment: #1: web browser is running on the same machine as web server
#2: I'll go through the article, otherwise, I found a better alternative to using the Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think most probably it's a matter of the security settings of the server where the JSP files, probably the server (doesn't allow exec calls). So you will have to tune the security settings of the server to allow the call.

Be aware that this may be a security risk.

Comment: I am running it on my local apache tomcat6 server.... I found a work around anyways; I basically used a PDF2Text library instead.